# SSIS2012 Error - Attempt to add a row to the data flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssis-2012, dataflow

as shown in the subject I am encountering the following error:

```
Description: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.

Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on FFS - POS Journal returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

However, what is odd is that it is only an issue when running on a server. For instance, i can debug the package successfully on my local machine, whereas if the job runs on a server (Same database, same everything), it throws the error above. I tried doing a 4-way conditional split in the DFT to improve performance (4 different conditions, 4 different ETL tables being loaded simultaneously). Is there a chance that this is just somehow too much for the server to handle? This is going into a SQL server 2012 database.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: It feels like its memory related. How much memory is allocated to SQL Server on the server compared your local environment?

Comment: I've gotten this error before and found it was one of those generic error messages that could be a lot of things.   I don't even remember what it was or how I fixed it in my case.   Which component is generating the error?

Comment: I found the issue. I didn't really think it'd be an issue but i over-estimated the VM I was using. It only had 4 GB of ram and 2 cpu cores. Telling it to run 4 threads i'm sure was messing it up, and the RAM was capped while it was running. Anyways, adding 2 more cores and raising to 8GB fixed the issue. Thanks kevchadders your comment lead me to check the memory usage.